# "Does anyone in your family dislike to cook?" vs "Does anyone in your family doesn't like to cook?"

Tags: grammar

Is it possible to say `"Does anyone in your family doesn't like to cook?"` or is it more correct to say `"Does anyone in your family dislike to cook?"`

Comment: There's a *very* extensive answer to [Can to-infinitives be used after the verb “dislike”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/357866/) as asked on ELU some years ago. Short answer: Centuries ago you it was perfectly natrural to use the infinitive form after both ***like*** AND ***dislike***, but over the years constructions like *I **dislike to answer** questions* have fallen out of favour, so even though it's still "grammatical", you should always use the continuous / gerund form today: *I **dislike answering** questions*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of the sentences is correct (or, at the very least, natural).

> *Does anyone in your family doesn't like to cook?

In this one, you're repeating *does* twice. It should either be:

> Does anyone in your family not like to cook?
>
> Doesn't anyone in your family like to cook?

with the former probably being closer to a genuine question and the latter being closer to an expression of doubt/disbelief.

> ?Does anyone in your family dislike to cook?

While you'll [still find *dislike* alongside an infinitive sometimes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/357866/can-to-infinitives-be-used-after-the-verb-dislike), modern English almost exclusively associates *dislike* with nouns and gerunds:

> Does anyone in your family dislike cooking?